# how to get the use-defined permission of another application

Tags: android, permissions

An application defines a content provider with the specified permission, and my application is intended to access that provider. How can I know what permissions to request in order to access that provider? May I have to hack the Manifest.xml of that application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use uses-permission tag in your app Manifest file

For Example , Extract from Android Developer Site:

User Permissions

To read calendar data, an application must include the READ_CALENDAR permission in its manifest file. It must include the WRITE_CALENDAR permission to delete, insert or update calendar data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: If the necessary permission is the user-defined permission, which is not declared in any public website. For example, one application declares a provider called FooProvider with the read permission as "com.foo.readpermission". Another application wants to access FooProvider, how can it know which permission should it requests? Thanks!